# How to fetch data from api using map in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a problem how can I fetch multi-array data from API using map
error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TypeError: map is not a function ( fetch regional data using map )

```
const [coviddata, setCoviddata] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((codata) => setCoviddata(codata.data))
})

return (
    <>
    <h1>States</h1>
    {
        coviddata.map(
            (covax) => (
                <h3>{covax.regional.loc}</h3>
            )
        )
    }
    </>
)
```

}

API: https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest

Comment: `.then((codata) => setCoviddata(codata.data.regional))` and `const [coviddata, setCoviddata] = useState([]);` changes in your code. It will run. Map will work with array josn object not with simple object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'data' property you're trying to access from the results is not an array. Rather do this.

```js
const [coviddata, setCoviddata] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {


        fetch("https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((codata) => setCoviddata(codata.data.regional))
    });

    return (
        <>
            <h1>States</h1>
            {
                coviddata.map(
                    (covax, index) => (
                        <h3 key={index}>{covax.loc}</h3>
                    )
                )
            }
        </>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because initial of `coviddata` is `undefined`. So `coviddata.map` will show this error. `coviddata` only change to array when api call success.

You just update decalre state with empty array:

```
const [coviddata, setCoviddata] = useState([]);
```

Or you can use `optional chaining` to check data is not `undefined`:

```
coviddata?.map(...)
```

Comment: you are missing the empty array